# Django - passing extra arguments into default callable function

Tags: django, python-2.7, import, python-import

## Original Title: cannot get **import** to work properly

I am trying to generate a function which will create a random alphanumeric number and make it as default value of a model field in django.

So for a single model I did like this:

```
# utils.py
def generate_random_unique_code_for_model():
    from .models import mymodel 
    while 1:
        code = random_code()  #my custom function to generate random alphanumeric
        try:
            mymodel.objects.get(myfield=code)
        except mymodel.DoesNotExist:
            return code

 #models.py
 class mymodel(models.Model):
     #other fields
     myfield = models.CharField(default=generate_random_unique_code_for_model)
```

This code works fine, but now I have to provide similar function for another model, so to follow the DRY principle I am trying to make the model , fieldnames dynamic. So basically I am trying to accomplish `from some_app.models import some_model` inside my `generate_random_unique_code_for_model` function .

```
def get_model(location, model_name):
    try:
        module = __import__('.'.join(location), globals(), locals(), [model_name], -1)
        model_instance = getattr(module, model_name)
    except:
        raise ImportError(_('Could not import %(model_name)s from %(location)s') % {'model_name': model_name,
                                                                                    'location': '.'.join(location)})
    return model_instance


def generate_random_unique_code_for_model(location, model_name, field_name):
    model_object = get_model(location, model_name)
    kwargs = {field_name: ''}
    while 1:
        code = random_code()
        kwargs[field_name] = code
        try:
            model_object.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except model_object.DoesNotExist:
            return code
#models.py
class mymodel_name(models.Model):
    #other fields
    myfield_name = models.CharField(default=generate_random_unique_code_for_model(['myapp_name', 'mymodel_name'], 'myfield_name'))
```

While debuggin, when I do `dir(module)` while debugging I don't see `mymodel_name` in the list. Any workarounds please?

Comment: What are the values of `location` and `mode_name` [sic] that you are passing to `get_model()`?

Comment: @Evert `location=['myapp', 'models']` and `model_name='mymodel'`

Comment: Note that you don't specify the exact error you're getting. If you're just seeing your own error message ("Could not import mymodel from myapp.models"), that could be caused by anything, because you have a *catch-all `except` statement*: don't do that: catch the `ImportError` or whatever `__import__` raises.

Comment: Actually `model_instance = getattr(module, model_name)` line is failing to get the `model_name` because the module doesn't have model_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was default takes a callable function so whenever an instance of model is instantiated the default function is called. But since I called the  function in the second case whenever the server is started and models are loaded it was trying to load model before the model class was created. So the problem comes down to pass a callable function with parameters to default which is not possible as of now. So what I did is this:

```
def make_random():
    return generate_random_unique_code_for_model(['myapp_name', 'mymodel_name'], 'myfield_name')


class mymodel_name(models.Model):
    #other fields
    myfield_name = models.CharField(default=make_random)
```